# Time series analysis: How would I fit a Yt = a + bt + Zt model to data on r?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to fit the model `Yt = a + bt + Zt` to my `data`, where `Zt` is white noise.

Does the function `m=lm(data)` include white noise or would I need to add `Zt` on?

Comment: I think that by looking back at the equation you wrote and the model you are creating, you will find your answer.  You can also get additional help in `R` with the command `?lm()`

Comment: Which would you prefer: to analyze your data or to add random "noise" to your data and analyze that?  Which do you think would be more accurate and reproducible?

Comment: I think this might be borderline on-topic here: the way we write  models (with an explicit error term) is different from the way we actually code them (with the error term implicitly specified by the choice of fitting function).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one *describes* a model as containing an error term. For example, the standard linear model usually looks like

$$
\begin{align*}
Y &= \mathbf{BX} + \mathbf{U} \\ 
&\textrm{       or}\\
y_i &= \beta_0 +\beta_{1}x_{1} +  \beta_{2}x_{2} + \ldots + \beta_{p}x_{p} + \epsilon_i
\end{align*}
$$
Sometimes, the error term is described in more detail. For example, you might replace $\mathbf{U}$ or $\epsilon$  with $N(0, \sigma)$ to indicate that the errors are normally distributed.

However, when you go to actually *fit* the model, you do something like this (in R; Matlab, Python, Julia, etc are similar):

```
linear.model <- lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3)
```

The error term is not *directly* specified in the model, but is instead implied by your choice of fitting functions: the linear model assumes (multivariate) normal-distributed errors.

However, if a different error distribution is required, people often turn to general*ized* linear models (GLMs), which allow you to specify a different error distribution. This is typically done by providing a second argument (e.g., the `family` argument to R's `glm`), instead of adjusting the model specification directly.

In summary, no, you don't include the error term in your call.